# Method "showDate" has type "undefined" in the component definition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have written some date processing utility in the changeFormatDate.js file, used to format datetime,

```
 'changeFormatDate.js'   

 const showDate = function (d) {
return moment(d).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
 }
```

and this function I tried to render in HTML template.

```
 'template.vue'
       <template lang="pug">
              .data(v-for="(rata,index) in loan.schedule")
                  .values
                      span {{index+1}}
                      span {{showDate(rata.date)}}
   </template>

  <script>
    import { showDate } from "@/util/changeFormatDate.js";
    import moment from "moment";

    export default {
       name: "TimetableApplication",
       props: {
       loan: { type: Object, required: true }
 },
    methods: {
     showDate
  }
};
</script>
```

But still I have an error " Method "showDate" has type "undefined" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?" How can I define properly to use it in templae HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed **export** in "changeFormatDate.js"

https://javascript.info/import-export